# Query if else if else check true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Hello i want to check if a div has the class active.
the first item works, after that it stops. Can someone tell me how to fix this?
(Its a slider, so it has to work not on click.) It slides automatic.
http://i61.tinypic.com/28h2zb6.jpg

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('#211').hasClass('item active')){
            $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "blue");
            console.log("werkt1!");}
   else if ($('#218').hasClass('item active')){
            $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "#005993");
            console.log("werkt2!");}

    else if ($('#219').hasClass('active')){
            $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "#005993");
            console.log("werkt3!");}
});

</script>
```

the number is the id of the image slider. and the .item .active is when the slide is active.
Greetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `else if`, because it stops after the first block works.

Instead use `if() { }` blocks.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#211').hasClass('item active')) {
            $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "blue");
            console.log("Works!");
        } 
        if ($('#218').hasClass('item active')) {
            $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "#005993");
            console.log("works2!");
        }
        if ($('#219').hasClass('active')) {
            $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "#005993");
            console.log("works3!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. do i have to let the (document).ready out? I only get the first console.log "Works!" back

Comment: Are you sure #218 and #219 are active ? It definitely should be working and the issue isn't Javascript related.

Document.ready simply means the script is executed when the page has finished loading.

Comment: You told me yes but they're not active... `class="item"` instead of `class="item active"`

Comment: Its a slider, first #211 is active. After 8 second slide #218 is active, and then #219 and then it starts over.

Comment: That explains why then. When you use `$(document).ready`, the code is executed when the page loads and only once. You'll need to execute the code again to check 8s later for instance. I advise using *events* to do so instead.

Comment: thanks for ur help! i will look at that. that was why i asked for leaving the doc.ready out ;)

Comment: No problem, but I couldn't have guessed since you didn't say that it becomes active after a certain time only. Try to be more specific the next time you ask something, you'll get better answers faster.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need else condition if you want multiple conditions to be executed:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   if ($('#211').hasClass('item active')){
      $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "blue");
      console.log("Works!");}
   if ($('#218').hasClass('item active')){
      $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "#005993");
      console.log("works2!");}
   if ($('#219').hasClass('active')){
      $('.vandaag').css("background-color", "#005993");
      console.log("works3!");}
  });
```